# Applet and JSF Integration - example

Tags: java, jsf, applet

Is there a tutorial or a simple applet example with JSF? How do I perform a request to a Managed Bean from an applet?

Comment: You can also do it via Applet-JavaScript as described here: [Applet-JavaScript](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a JSF managed bean. It is not suitable for this job. Use a servlet or a webservice. To exchange data, use the session scope with an unique autogenerated key which you pass as parameter to the applet beforehand. This way the data will be available to JSF as well.

Answer (score 1):

JSF (and hence managed beans) executes on the server to produce HTML; An applet executes on the client's machine - so you can't just pass a reference to a managed bean to an applet.

If you just need to pass a value from a managed bean to an Applet at start time, you can use the `<param>` sub-element of the  [tag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet.html) to pass this value.

If you need some kind of dynamic access to the managed bean, it's going to be a lot harder - basically, you'll need to build some kind of web service that's backed by the managed bean so that the applet can make http requests back to the server to get the values it needs.