# JSF / Applet integration

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, applet

In our current prototype most the standard HTML controls are replaced by an applet, most important the form submission is triggered by the applet.

Is there a way to call an associated action on the server side much the same way as with

```
<h:commandButton action="#{ctrl.doit}"/>?
```

This article [Applet and JSF Integration - example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518933/applet-and-jsf-integration-example) had the same question but not a suitable answer. The applet is a drop in replacement for a form from the viewpoint of the server. It fills dedicated (hidden) fields and submits - no direct communication to a server.

EDIT

So far, i understand there are these integration possibilities:

- add a (hidden) UICommand and trigger it via JavaScript
- Implement a UICommand of your own. As far as i understand, i'd define a hidden parameter for marking the applet as the form submit control, in the request processing cycle the UICommand implementation will find out and trigger the action. Maybe one should implement a virtual control (comparable to f:viewParam) as an endpoint for MethodExpressions.
- Attach a listener, either to a (random) control or a more general event listener and do your stuff here. In this case, how is navigation done?

Comment: It will be great to share your code. Apparently, there are no many Applet-JSF resources on the web. Regards,

Comment: This applet integration comes down to a simple JavaScript call. Get JSObject.getWindow() and let it "eval" the JavaScript that will click the hidden OK button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not** possible without having a physical JSF view in the very same page which has the applet embedded. So, you should really at least have a `<h:form>` with a `<h:commandButton>` in the same page, if necessary hidden by CSS `display: none;`. This is simply because JSF needs to have a view state of that form in the server side, among others to prevent [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)-like attacks. If having a physical `<h:form>` in the page is not a problem for you (which seems to be true in your *particular* case), then you can just let Applet fill the fields (if any) and click the button of the form using [Applet-JavaScript](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html) communication.

Other than that, a simple servlet or a real webservice API like JAX-RS/JAX-WS is really the best way. JSF is a component based MVC framework and not a webservice framework. That's what my answer in that linked question is trying to make clear: *use the right tool for the job*.

Comment: Thank you! Having a form is necessary by design anyway - i only searched for a way to skip the hidden button. The applet is not used as a webservice client. Just imagine it beeing a fancy button implementation. I'll add some remarks in the question about implementing such behavior... B.t.w - you're a really GREAT contributor. You always provide accurate responses, fast, supporting and understandable. Simply great.

Comment: There's no other way to invoke a managed bean action than by a physical `UICommand` component. You could however abuse a `valueChangeListener` or hook on some setter method, but this is awful.

Comment: sorry for nagging - i added this hymn above via edit yesterday, but you already answered when i committed. Just in case you missed it :-)